# Contrapositive of $A\subset B\implies \min A\geq \min B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

After I learned about the existence of such a concept as a contrapositive, I always try to translate any statements into a contrapositive.  And every time I fail.  I haven't found a general technique for this yet. I think that if I know the statement and its contrapositive form, it will give me a better understanding.

The statement :$$A\subset B \implies \min A \geq \min B.$$

Its contrapositive form must look like $$\neg (\min A\geq \min B)\implies \neg (A\subset B).$$

The first thing which comes to mind is $$\min A<\min B \implies B\subseteq A.$$

On the other hand I think I must write down what I mean by $A\subset B$ and I get

$$\neg (\min A\geq \min B)\implies \neg (x\in A \implies x\in B ).$$

And then I get $$\min A<\min B \implies x\in A, x\notin B$$ which looks very strange.

**Question**: What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Second one is correct; reading $A,B$ as e.g. set of natural numbers, if $\min A \lt \min B$ then this means that there is some number (call it $x$) that is in $A$ but not in $B$.

Comment: Example: $A = \{ 1,2,3 \}$ and $B = \{ 2,3,4,5,6 \}$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! I understand your example. But I do not understand why we get "...there is some x in A...". I do not see $\exists$ symbol.

Comment: Because $\lnot (A \subset B)$ is NOT $(B \subseteq A)$. We have that $(A \subseteq B)$ is defined as $\forall x (x \in A \to x \in B)$; thus, negating it, we get: $\exists x (x \in A \land x \notin B)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! I did not know it. You very helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sim(A\subset B)\equiv A\not\subset B$ rather than $B\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Nitin’s answer: $A$ isn’t a proper subset of $B$ means precisely that
*EITHER* some element of $A$ isn’t in $B\;$ *OR* $\;A=B,$ that is, $$⊄\;\iff \\\big(A=B\quad\lor\quad \exists x{\in}A\; x\not\in B \big). $$